# Flutter CustomClipper

Tags: flutter, clipper

I am using Custom Clipper while creating these two widgets in Flutter, but there is a problem, how can I create it?

[image]

Update: can be used to crop from right side

```
class CustomRightClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.37, 30);
    path.lineTo(0, 30);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomRightClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: Please include your current code to make it easier to provide a solution.

Comment: Also, please specify the problem you are facing with your code.

Comment: I added my code but I didn't get the structure I wanted because I don't understand exactly how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For path will be like below, you can pass the gap with parameters or use relative width.

```dart
class BottomRightClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  const BottomRightClipper({required this.isLeft});
  final bool isLeft;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    if (isLeft) { /// separated to make it easier to understand for everyone
      path.moveTo(0, 0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
      path.lineTo(size.width - 40, size.height);
      path.lineTo(0, size.height);
      path.lineTo(0, 0);
    } else { //for right
      path.moveTo(40, 0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
      path.lineTo(0, size.height);
      path.lineTo(40, 0);
    }
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(BottomRightClipper oldClipper) {
    return isLeft != oldClipper.isLeft;
  }
}
```

[image]

I will suggest to use `shape` parameter on different button. The extend OutlinedBorder or ShapeBorder and provide this same path.

Comment: thank you very much, i created such a structure to trim the right side. I'm adding the current version to the question section.